# Console closes immediately, so output is unreadable

Tags: c#

```
 using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;

using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1 
{
    class Program
{
        public static void Fibonacci_Iterative(int n)
    {
        int a = 0, b = 1, c = 0;
        Console.Write("{0} {1}", a, b);

        for (int i = 2; i < n; i++)
        {
            c = a + b;
            Console.Write(" {0}", c);
            Console.ReadKey();
            a = b;
            b = c;

        }
    }

    int main()
    {
        Fibonacci_Iterative(15);
        return 0;

    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

    }
}
}
```

This code makes the console appear and gives no errors, but the console disappears before becoming legible.

Any help on making this readable would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Press ctrl+F5 instead of F5

Comment: Add `Console.ReadLine()` to end of main

Comment: @doctor thank you! it fixed that problem, but now the console is not writing anything.

Comment: @Shamison try my solution, it will print your output and wait for exit

Answer (score 0):

Add `Console.ReadLine()` or something along the lines of `while(true);` at the end of your logic flow.

Also it seems like

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

}
```

is your start method which does nothing (this is where you should call your function).

Answer (score 0):

Add a `Console.ReadLine();` at the end, and it should wait and input before closing.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this, put `Console.ReadKey()` at the end of the program so that it wait for key press, also remove your version of `main` method

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;

using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1 
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Fibonacci_Iterative(int n)
        {
           int a = 0, b = 1, c = 0;
           Console.Write("{0} {1}", a, b);

           for (int i = 2; i < n; i++)
           {
               c = a + b;
               Console.Write(" {0}", c);

               a = b;
               b = c;

           }
       }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
       Fibonacci_Iterative(15);
       Console.ReadKey();
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you. I will mark it as solved when the timer ends.